# How to write Junit test case for List<ItemComment> attribute inner class

Tags: java, junit

```
public class Item {
      private long id;
      private String name;    
      private List<ItemComment> itemComments;
    public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<ItemComment> getItemComments() {
    return itemComments;
}

public void setItemComments(List<ItemComment> itemComments) {
    this.itemComments = itemComments;
}
```

}
}

and this is ItemComment class:

```
 public class ItemComment {
        private long id;
        private String name;
        private String comment;
    }
```

and this is removeEmojis():

```
protected void removeEmojis(Item item) {
            if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(item.getDescription())) {
                item.setDescription(EmojiParser.removeAllEmojis(item.getDescription()));
            }
            if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(item.getItemComments())) {
                for(ItemComment itemComments : item.getItemComments()) {
                    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(itemComments.getComment())) {
                    temComments.setComment(EmojiParser.removeAllEmojis(itemComments.getComment()));
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

This is my junit test case :

```
@Test
  public void testRemoveEmoji() throws Exception { 
    Items items = getSampleItems("/json/ItemObjectWithEmojiContent.json");
    List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    itemList.addAll(items.getItemsList());
   
    for(Item item : itemList) {
        assertNotNull(item.getItemComments());
        for(ItemComment itemComments : item.getItemComments()) {
            this.starcImportProcessor.removeEmojis(item);
            assertEquals("(Open -> In Progress -> Open -> Closed)", item.getDescription());
            assertEquals("Test comment", itemComments.getComment());
            
        }
    }
    
  
  
  }
```

I have to write Junit for this removeEmoji() and compare the comments in junit as expected result and actual result?
How to write the Junit and new in junit test cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should provide more information about your classes, anyway here the code so far:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Item {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private List<ItemComment> itemComments;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<ItemComment> getItemComments() {
        return itemComments;
    }

    public void setItemComments(List<ItemComment> itemComments) {
        this.itemComments = itemComments;
    }

}
```

and the ItemComment class:

```
public class ItemComment {

    private String comment;

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

}
```

For the test, is important to note you should init Item class in some ways, here the idea:

```
public class ItemTest {

    @Test
    public void commentTest() {
        // I want to write junit test case for List having comment as a attribute and
        // the comment what is there and what is coming i have to compare
        Item input = new Item();
        // your item input
        
        assertNotNull(input.getItemComments());
        for (ItemComment item : input.getItemComments()) {
            if (item.getComment()!=null) {
                // your test logic here
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Updated answer**

Given this code:

```
protected void removeEmojis(Item item) {
            if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(item.getDescription())) {
                item.setDescription(EmojiParser.removeAllEmojis(item.getDescription()));
            }
            if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(item.getItemComments())) {
                for(ItemComment itemComments : item.getItemComments()) {
                    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(itemComments.getComment())) {
                    temComments.setComment(EmojiParser.removeAllEmojis(itemComments.getComment()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And this request:

> I have to write Junit for this removeEmoji() and compare the comments
> in junit as expected result and actual result? How to write the Junit
> and new in junit test cases.

Your test code could be:

public class Test {

```
@Test
public void removeEmojisTEst() {
    // your tests must be incremental, so start from null:
    removeEmojis(null); // this method trigger a nullpointerException, so update your code to check for nulls first
    Item input = new Item();
    removeEmojis(input);
    // now we must check what an empty input does
    assertNull(input.getDescription()); // my speculations on your code
    assertNull(input.getItemComments()); // my speculations on your code
    // then we set a description, but empty;
    input.setDescription("");
    removeEmojis(input);
    assertTrue(input.getDescription().isEmpty());
    // now with random string
    input.setDescription("AAA");
    removeEmojis(input);
    assertTrue(input.getDescription().isEmpty()); // this depends on what EmojiParser.removeAllEmojis does
    // etc...
}
```

}

Now Junit tests are helpful to ask questions on how something is written, so why do you have one method for both removeEmoji from description and item comments?
Maybe you can split in two, so you can test them with two unit tests

Comment: How to write assertEquall method if comments having lots of comment and I need to compare all the comments to expected result to actual result.

Comment: "divide et impera" or in other words, divide your problem in smaller problems, you can build private methods in your class to check your conditions

Comment: I wrote this but unble to check all the comments

Comment: could you please update your question with all the code and properly formatted?

Comment: Like in json file it is coming lots of comments and I have to compare each comment to my actual result to expected result.

Comment: Could you please check my code. I already updated the code

Comment: No In only  one method i have to write for description and comments.and the attributes are coming json file

Comment: Like I have to compare expected result and actual result like in comment have a test Like "Test comment" but my expected result should be remove emoji from comment"Test comment"

Comment: Like:  assertEquals("Test comment", itemComments.getComment());